# trying to regex in python

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, urllib

*Can anyone please help me understand this code snippet, from http://garethrees.org/2007/05/07/python-challenge/ Level2*

```
>>> import urllib
>>> def get_challenge(s):
...     return urllib.urlopen('http://www.pythonchallenge.com/pc/' + s).read()
...
>>> src = get_challenge('def/ocr.html')
>>> import re
>>> text = re.compile('<!--((?:[^-]+|-[^-]|--[^>])*)-->', re.S).findall(src)[-1]
>>> counts = {}
>>> for c in text: counts[c] = counts.get(c, 0) + 1
>>> counts
```

http://garethrees.org/2007/05/07/python-challenge/

`re.compile('<!--((?:[^-]+|-[^-]|--[^>])*)-->', re.S).findall(src)[-1]` why we have [-1] here what's the purpose of it? is it Converting that to a list?  **

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. `re.findall()` returns a list of all the matches. Have a look at [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/re.html).

> *re.findall(pattern, string, flags=0)*
>
> Return all non-overlapping matches of pattern in string, **as a list of
>   strings.** The string is scanned left-to-right, and matches are returned
>   in the order found. If one or more groups are present in the pattern,
>   return a list of groups; this will be a list of tuples if the pattern
>   has more than one group. Empty matches are included in the result
>   unless they touch the beginning of another match.

When calling `[-1]` on the result, the first element *from the end of the list* is accessed.

For example;

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> a[-1]
5
```

And also:

```
>>> re.compile('.*?-').findall('-foo-bar-')[-1]
'bar-'
```

Comment: I got findall is for matching, i'm fine with it.  However what makes someone insert [-1 ] at the end of re.compile('<!--((?:[^-]+|-[^-]|--[^>])*)-->', re.S).findall(src)[-1] ?  Couldn't understand his intention.

Comment: It's simply array access - don't be fooled by the negative index! :)

Comment: But by putting [1] it's working fine! :/ and Could you also please explain what's going here in this line?  for c in text: counts[c] = counts.get(c, 0) + 1

Comment: That line is building a dictionary of the frequencies of each character in `text`. The zero in `get(c, 0)` is the default that is returned if `c` was not previously in the dictionary, but otherwise the count is simply incremented by `1` for each occurance.

Comment: I tried this pattern (<!--((?:[^-]+|-[^-]|--[^>])*)-->, r.S ), r.S is for all match(dot All) right?  in regex interpreter to check for matches inside the page source text content ('!@#$%^&*@#$%#$^%#$^$#%^#') of the challenge . It gives a match only when i remove <!-- --> otherwise it gives null.  why is that?

Answer (score 0):

It's already a list. And if you have a list `myList`, `myList[-1]` returns the last element in that list.

Read this: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#lists.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, so does putting a [] after an expression converts that into a list?? Bec if i put [1] it works the same way for [-1] but not for [2].

Comment: It was already a list. [] just retrieves an element or slice from the list. Changing the number in there is just going to change which element it accesses. Check out the page I linked to for more examples about list indexing and slices.

Comment: I got confused because if i try to print (text) it goes on like a big chunk, but if i keep [1]/[-1]  at the end , it prints line by line.

Comment: Yeah! i got it now. Very eloquent description :)

Comment: I tried this pattern ((<!--((?:[^-]+|-[^-]|--[^>])*)-->, r.S ), r.S is for all match(dot All) right?  in regex interpreter to check for matches inside the page source text  content ('!@#$%^&*@#$%#$^%#$^$#%^#') of the challenge . It gives a match only when i remove <!-- --> otherwise it gives null.  why is that?